# Environment variables hierarchy & path vs PATH

Tags: emacs, terminal, environment-variables, command-prompt, javac

This is what I have set my environment variables to for the `emacs`, `javac`, `java` commands to work in the Command Prompt.

variable : `path` 
value : `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin;C:\emacs\bin`

- Why is it that if I place the `emacs` folder first, only emacs works, but `javac` and `java` will not?
  *(I have seen both used in instructions, so are they the same?)*
- Why is it that `javac` and `java` will only work if `path` is used as the variable name (as opposed to `PATH`?

I am running Windows 8.1 Enterprise.

Comment: Environment variables are case-insensitive in Windows. I've seen programs make a private copy of the environment and mistakenly use case-sensitive comparisons. But CMD doesn't do that.

Comment: You shouldn't replace `PATH` like that. Almost always you should simply append or prepend to the existing value. And never use quotes, not that you appear to be doing that, but I've seen people assume that paths with spaces need quotes in `PATH`, which in general breaks common ways it's used such as in WinAPI `SearchPath`.

Comment: `PATH` is searched in order sequentially, so the order of entries can sometimes be crucial for finding the right executable or DLL with a given name.

Comment: @eryksun But my question is how do you know whether to append or prepend the path to the existing value? Why do some programs (e.g. `javac` / `java`) only work when it is before others (e.g. `emacs`)?

Comment: How in particular does javac fail when the JDK path is placed after "C:\emacs\bin"? Is there some executable or DLL in the latter directory that's conflicting with another one that javac expects to find on `PATH`?

Comment: @eryksun The error that arises is `'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` I don't think there is anything that conflicts with another file in the bin folder.

Comment: In that case CMD simply can't find javac.exe. Include an example `PATH` that fails, copied directly from the output of `set path`.